# Converting Time from Excel to seconds

Tags: c#, excel, time

I have a function in c# to convert Time in Excel cell's, in the hh:mm:ss format, to seconds.

But when I get cell's with more than 10.000hours, it doesn't work.

Any ideas why it does not work with bigger hours?

```
String time  = (Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDouble(newWs.get_Range("X" + i, "X" + i).Value + "") * 86400)) + "";
```

TIA

Comment: Debug it and post the _exact_ value that you get from `newWs.get_Range("X" + i, "X" + i).Value` - including it's type - is it a string or a double?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?  Is an error being thrown?

Comment: a format exception: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: What type you get back from `get_Range`? Does the behavior change when you set a specific cell type (number, text, ...) in Excel?

Comment: @chimino totally agree with D Stanley.. need the value to debug this bug. Kindly share the info to proceed...